# Compute the real part of the following complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

$Re \left(\cfrac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}}\right)$

Approach: Take $e^{i \theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, $e^{i -\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$

$$\cfrac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}}=\cfrac{1-e^{in\theta}e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}}$$

and then I am trying to substitute the expression to see if I can get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*} \frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}
&= \frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta/2} - e^{-i(n+1)\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2} - e^{-i\theta/2}} \cdot \frac{e^{i(n+1)\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}} \\ 
&= \frac{\sin \frac{n+1}{2}\theta}{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}} e^{in\theta/2} \\
&= \frac{\sin \frac{n+1}{2}\theta}{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}} \left(\cos \frac{n\theta}{2} + i\sin \frac{n\theta}{2}\right),
\end{align*}$$

the real part of which is simply $$\frac{\sin \frac{n+1}{2}\theta \cos \frac{n}{2}\theta}{\sin \frac{1}{2}\theta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the facts that $$\sum_{j=0}^na^j=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$ and that the real part of a finite sum equals the sum of the real parts of the summands we get that
\begin{align*}
\Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right)&=\Re\left(\sum_{j=0}^ne^{i\theta j}\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\Re(e^{i\theta j})\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n \cos(j\theta)
\end{align*}

This is one answear to your question. However, if you wish to express the real part not by a sum with $n+1$ terms, you could follow the method given by @heropup

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Remember the geometric progressions on the numerator, and you can cancel de factor on the denominator, then all is easy.

Comment: This expresses the result as a sum of $n+1$ terms, and if one wants to compute the value in question one must go back to the expression one started from. So, no, this is not the way to go.